# Does Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin supports stored procedures or custom functions

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Does Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin supports stored procedures or custom functions? Unfortunately I can not find any documentation on it. Apache Tinkerpop supports user defined steps. Other graph databases (e.g. Orient DB) support custom functions as well

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs) [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-use-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs), it seems to be *implied* that CosmosDB supports user defined functions and stored procedures only when using the Core (SQL) API.

However, I verified myself that you **can** create UDFs and SPs even with the Gremlin API. I created a new CosmosDB account with the Gremlin API and ran the commands found in [this notebook](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-notebooks/blob/master/5.%20StoredProcedures.ipynb) (if you enable the Notebooks feature when creating the account, you will see all the sample notebooks in data explorer). Here's what it looks like:

[image: GremlinAPI stored procedures]

Comment: Thank you for your response. Links you have attached are not relevant to Gremlin. Please do not assume. Yes, Azure UI shows stored procedures and custom functions, but there is no point in them if they do not support  gremlin queries https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/20115355-gremlin-queries-from-stored-procedures

Comment: Please describe a scenario you want to achieve and I'll do my best to recreate it. In your question you simply ask whether it's possible to create stored procedures in a cosmosdb account that uses the Gremlin API and I think I answered that.

Comment: If we talk about support and not just UI - stored procedures are useless for Cosmos DB in Graph/Gremlin mode. You can use there only syntax for document mode in stored procs. You won't be even able to query data out of graph of the same spdtest database. Try to have stored proc with gremlin query returning vertices count - g.V().count(). You can execute such query via Databases explorer so why not to execute it via stored proc or UDF.